# How can I use Siri Shortcuts to show a specific page in my app?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, ios12

I want to advanced research Shortcuts technology. So here are some questions:

- Can Siri shortcuts be used in any type of app? Because of SiriKit only working in tourism, chatting etc.
- Now using shortcuts. Can I jump to my app showing specific page by Siri？

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can Siri shortcuts be used in any type of app? Because of SiriKit only
>   working in tourism, chatting etc.

Yes, any. They aren't tied to any specific domain. They are custom.

> Now using shortcuts. Can I jump to my app showing specific page by
>   Siri？

Yes.

---

The code below shows the easiest way on how to show a specific page by Siri, it's called *"Donating a Shortcut"* via `NSUserActivity`. But you could achieve the same by defining a custom `INIntent`.

**Step 1:**

In `Info.plist`, under `NSUserActivityTypes` add an activity type string: `com.app.viewPage`

**Step 2:**

Create activity:

```
let viewPageActivityType = "com.app.viewPage"

let viewPageActivity: NSUserActivity = {
    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: viewPageActivityType)
    userActivity.title = "View Page"
    userActivity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "View Page"
    userActivity.isEligibleForSearch = true
    userActivity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
    return userActivity
}()
```

Then add it to your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userActivity = viewPageActivity
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Handle it in `UIApplicationDelegate` method (this method will get called if a user presses the Shortcut, or activates in from Siri via voice):

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    if userActivity.activityType == viewPageActivityType {
        print("open the `ViewController` here")
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

---

After the user opens the `ViewController` once, they may get it suggested in the lock screen and search suggestions. They can also go to `Settings -> Siri & Search -> My Shortcuts` to define a custom phrase to perform the action using voice.

To debug this, make sure to use a device (not simulator). Then go to `Settings -> Developer -> Enable "Display Recent Shortcuts" and "Display Donations on Lock Screen"`.

There are a lot of great resources on this:

- [Apple Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts?language=objc)
- [Introduction to Siri Shortcuts WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/)
- [Donating Shortcuts Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts?language=objc)
- [Relevant Shortcuts Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/relevant_shortcuts?language=objc)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot

Comment: thanks，I read SoupChef demo, But I hava a question? I can't find OrderSoupIntent file in the project.And This OrderSoupIntent,There is a OrderSoupIntentHandling protocol,and I don't know who call this protocol method.

Comment: @Corbin The files are automatically generated from `Intents.intentdefinition` file. The "OrderSoup" custom intent automatically generates a class + protocol. This can be customized via "Identity Inspector" in right panel in Xcode, under "Custom Class." You can just search where `OrderSoupIntentHandling` is used. It's used in `SoupChefIntents` target, `IntentHandler` class/file.

Comment: I found that the 'OrderSoupIntentHandler' class only wirtes the implementation of NewWordIntentHandling protocol method.So I hava a question?Where setup delegate？I use oc, but I don't know how to write xxx.delegate = self.If I only write the NewWordIntentHandling protocol, this method can't be call.Because I don't setup delegate .

Comment: This is working really fine for me. But how is it possible to add multiple activities in this way?

Comment: @mh-itc yes you can create multiple activities and an app probably has multiple different `UIViewController`'s. If you want multiple different activities on the same view controller, I'm not sure u can do it using the code I posted, but you can roll a more custom solution by using custom `INIntent`. Short answer: yes, but probably not with this exact code.